# Angular JS not loading view

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

I'm trying to get my first AngualarJS app going but it won't work for some reason. Been googling for a while now and haven't found a solution that works for me yet.
Can anyone with some AngularJS exp see what's wrong with my code?
Appreciate any help!

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-extended.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Java Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <nav class="col-xs-12">
        <table id="navTable">
            <tr>
                <td><p>view 1</p></td>
                <td><p>view 2</p></td>
                <td><p>view 3</p></td>
                <td><p>view 4</p></td>
                <td><p>view 5</p></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </nav>

    <!-- View Placeholder -->
    <article data-ng-view="" class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
        Views goes here...
    </article>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

        app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

            $routeProvider
                .when('/', 
                {
                    controller: 'basicController',
                    templateUrl: '/partials/viewOne.html'
                })
                .when('/menu', {
                    controller: 'basicController',
                    templateUrl: '/partials/viewTwo.html'
                })
                .when('/map', 
                {
                    controller: 'basicController',
                    templateUrl: '/partials/viewThree.html'
                })
                .when('/info', 
                {
                    controller: 'basicController',
                    templateUrl: '/partials/viewFour.html'
                })
                .when('/offers', 
                {
                    controller: 'basicController',
                    templateUrl: '/partials/viewFive.html'
                })
                .when('/account', 
                {
                    controller: 'basicController',
                    templateUrl: '/partials/viewSix.html'
                })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
        }]);

        app.controller('basicController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            $scope.message = "Hello!";

        }]);

    </script>

    <footer class="col-xs-12 navbar-fixed-bottom">

    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to start with advising you to follow [this official tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07): it shows you the beginnings of how to build an app with AngularJS and views. The reason I would advise this is because there are quite a few basic elements that are missing from the script, mostly the `<a>` tags. Maybe you can start from the tutorial and build your own code based on that.

Remarks about your code:

- Add all your script tags with javascript in your `<head>`. These will then in turn be run by a browser, making sure that all dependencies are met
- You forgot a comma after "app" in your module initialization
- Most important, you should change your `<p>` tags to `<a>` tags if you want views to work. Angular uses the `<a>`-tags to make navigation to different views possible. The `href` attribute of an `<a>` tag is used for this. Check my code below and you can see that my `href` attributes are linked to the routeprovider in the when clause.

Below you will find your adjusted code. Hope it helps!

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title></title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-extended.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
        <!-- Java Script -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

            app.config(function($routeProvider){

                $routeProvider
                    .when('/', 
                    {
                        controller: 'basicController',
                        templateUrl: 'partials/viewOne.html'
                    })
                    .when('/menu', {
                        controller: 'basicController',
                        templateUrl: 'partials/viewTwo.html'
                    })
                    .when('/map', 
                    {
                        controller: 'basicController',
                        templateUrl: 'partials/viewThree.html'
                    })
                    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
            });

            app.controller('basicController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
                $scope.message = "Hello!";
            }]);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <nav class="col-xs-12">
                <table id="navTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="#">view 1</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#/menu">view 2</a></td>
                        <td><a href="#/map">view 3</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </nav>

            <!-- View Placeholder -->
            <article data-ng-view="" class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
                Views goes here...
            </article>

            <footer class="col-xs-12 navbar-fixed-bottom"></footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, read through the tutorial but I'm still not getting it to work.
If i click any link in the navTable it does redirect to the specified view. I can see the url update but the html in the view is not loaded in the <ng-view> tag.

Comment: Found the problem. I had `templateUrl: '/partials/viewOne.html'` and didn't see you changed it to `templateUrl: 'partials/viewOne.html'`

Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to see it works. If my answer answered your question, please flag it as solved